What is the specific line of this idea of Kant's Critique of Pure Reason?
I remember there is one specific sentence but only have a dim impression of this idea. Would love to learn what is the exact sentence:
This aligns with the idea that one must either choose to remain ignorant and indifferent or delve deeply to fully comprehend and acknowledge all perceptions. Kant advocates for the latter, urging a thorough and critical engagement with our cognitive faculties to attain genuine understanding.
Very much appreciated for any help!

To "delve deeply to fully comprehend and acknowledge all perceptions" is not really what Kant's Critique of Pure Reason is about. He formulates his major question himself, "how is a priori knowledge possible?" (such as knowledge of mathematics and basic natural laws), and scrutinizes our cognition, separated into reason/understanding and sensibility/perception, to answer it. But the resulting answer, in a nutshell, is given in the preface, "to know something securely a priori he had to ascribe to the thing nothing except what followed necessarily from what he himself had put into it".

@yyln What is your question: Do you ask for a specific quote from Kant's "Critique of pure Reason" (CpR) which says "Either dvelve deeply or stay ignorant"? Or do you ask for the main ideas of CpR?

I flatter myself that I have…discovered the cause of…consequently the mode of removing – all the errors which have hitherto set reason at variance with itself…I have not returned an evasive answer to the questions of reason, by alleging the inability and limitation of the faculties of the mind; I have…examined them completely in the light of principles, and, after having discovered the cause of the doubts and contradictions into which reason fell, have solved them to its perfect satisfaction…I make bold to say that there is not a single metaphysical problem that does not find its solution…

The specific idea is to determine the limit of human reasoning. In order to avoid going beyond this limit and enter into a series of antinomies.
A result from Kant's work is to know which categories we use to build human experience. Experience is not an copy but a construction.
In any case, to understand Kant it is necessary to read his work. A good introduction is his preface to the second edition of the Critique of Pure Reason from 1787.
